# What is the meaning of "testotum"?

Tags: meaning

In the novel [*A Day Among The Liars*](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks06/0606901h.html#s17) by Edward Page Mitchell, there is this sentence:

> "My rod creaked and bent double," a stout, red-faced gentleman was saying, "and the birch spun like a testotum."

Please can anyone explain the meaning of "birch spun like a testotum"?

Comment: Try teetotum, I think that's the word you need. It's a spinning top.

Comment: This is Too Localised, searching Google Books for ["and the birch spun like a"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22and+the+birch+spun+like+a%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) establishes conclusively that OP's citation is a mistranscription of [teetotum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teetotum).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The word isn't found by [Onelook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=testotum&ls=a&loc=2osdf), but it suggests some others.

Searching Google for the sentence without *testotum* gives some alternate words.

- My rod creaked and bent double,” a stout, red-faced gentleman was saying, “and the birch spun like a tee-totum.
- "My rod creaked and bent double," a stout, red-faced gentleman was saying, "and the birch spun like a teetotum.

---

A [teetotum](http://www.onelook.com/?w=teetotum&loc=dym) is:

> A top, usually having four lettered sides, that is used to play various games of chance.

Images from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teetotum):

[image: Chinese teetotum] [image: A girl holding up a four-sided teetotum on Pieter Brueghel's Children's Games (1560)] [image: A twelve-sided teetotum]

It may be worth noting that *teetotum* isn't a well known word; at least I hadn't heard it before.

---

Project Gutenberg texts are scanned from books. Sometimes there can be mistakes with the OCR (optical character recognition), the computer program that guesses the letters, especially in older books with less clear type. Humans volunteers proof-read the text before release, but some mistakes can slip through, such as this one.

Comment: Do you mean... a teetotum is dreidel?

Comment: @Mitch: Yes, or something similar. Other definitions include: *a spinning top bearing letters of the alphabet on its four sides* and *such a top used as a die in gambling games* (Collins).